# How to solve Diophantine equations in $F_{p}$?

Tags: polynomials, nt.number-theory

For example, how to solve the equation $\sum^{p-1}_{i}x_{i}^{2}=0$ in $F_{p}$? This is not a homework problem. I think it should have a definite answer, so not an open problem. I just don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I want to ask is there any good bound for the number of solutions(sorry forgot to post in first place)?

Comment: The number of solutions up to simultaneous scaling by a non-zero element of $\mathbb{F}_p$ (if p>3) should be $\frac{p^{p-2}-1}{p-1}$ if $p=1 \pmod{4}$ and $\frac{p^{p-2}-1}{p-1}+p^{\frac{p-3}{2}}$ if $p=3 \pmod{4}$.

Comment: damiano, how can you show that?  I did some numerical work and conjectured it but I have no idea how such things are proven.

Comment: The way I computed it, was by using the Weil conjectures. In this case you can argue your way through using the fact that as soon as you have a solution you can find all the remaining ones by projection away from it (like in Bjorn's answer). What remains to show is what happens when the projection never contains a line (case 1) or when it does contain at least one (and hence two) (case 2).

Comment: My previous comment on the lines addresses the case of *p=5*; in general it might be slightly trickier, but I think that the same strategy will work. The condition on the prime is needed to split the cases according to the quadratic character of *-1*.

Comment: Thanks damiano! (I did not expect this will have anything to do with Weil conjecture)

Comment: The number of solutions was first worked out by Victor Amande Lebesgue (the number theorist, not the Lebesgue famous for his integration theory) in 1838 and was used for proving the quadratic reciprocity law. A simplified version of his proof was recently published by W. Castryck,  A shortened classical proof of the quadratic reciprocity law, Amer. Math. Monthly (2007). 

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a *deterministic* polynomial-time algorithm for finding solutions to diagonal equations of degree less than or equal to the number of variables over finite fields.  See [Christiaan van de Woestijne's thesis](http://www.opt.math.tugraz.at/~cvdwoest/).

(A solution of your example equation can be found much more simply, however: try small integers, not necessarily distinct... .  And for quadratic forms, the other solutions can be found by drawing lines through the point and intersecting with the quadric hypersurface: there will either be one more intersection point, or a whole line of points.)

Comment: Hi! I really thanks for the link of the paper. I will read it. 

Comment: Sorry for the impertinent remark, but a *deterministic* algorithm for finding all solutions to an equation in the variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ is obtained by plugging in all $q^n$ possible values and counting how many give solutions.  I can well believe the van de Woestijne's algorithm is better than this, but can you say exactly how?  

Comment: I don't really understand the part "the other solutions can be found by drawing lines through the point and intersecting with the quadric hypersurface: there will either be one more intersection point, or a whole line of points", I will read the paper. 

Comment: @Pete: Good point! I forgot to write the words "polynomial time" (not to mention "over finite fields"!)  It's fixed now.

Comment: @Pencil: Think about the analogous situation of rational solutions to x^2+y^2=1.  If you draw a line of rational slope through (-1,0), it will intersect the circle in two rational points: finding them involves solving a quadratic equation for which you already know one rational solution.  The same idea applies to degree 2 equations over any field, the only caveat being that sometimes the quadratic equation to be solved is the equation ax^2+by+c=0 where a,b,c are all zero (which means geometrically that the line is contained in the hypersurface defined by the degree 2 equation).

Comment: To amplify on what Bjorn said -- if you have one solution you can use it to rationally parametrize all others via pencils of line.  So the real problem is there a fast (i.e. polynomial time algorithm in log of the size of the finite field) algorithm to find one point.  It turns out that if you are given a quadratic non-residue (generator of the 2-sylow subgroup of $F^*$) then there is a deterministic poly time algorithm to find a solution.  This is still an open problem but van de Woestijne found a clever way around this for diagonal forms.

Answer (score 3):

You want to know if the sum of $p-1$ squares can be equal to 0 mod $p$.  I'll assume that you don't want to allow the trivial (all-zeroes) solution.

If $k$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$, not equal to $1$, then this is simple; take $x_1$ such that $x_1^2 = k$, take $x_2 = \ldots = x_{p-k+1} = 1$, and take $x_{p-k+2} = \ldots = x_{p-1} = 0$.

So the equation $x_1^2 + \cdots + x_{p-1}^2 = 0$ has solutions mod $p$ as long as there exists a quadratic residue mod $p$ which is not equal to $1$.  The number of quadratic residues mod $p$ is $\phi(p)/2$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function; if $\phi(p)/2 \ge 2$, or $\phi(p) \ge 4$, then there is at least one non-$1$ quadratic residue mod p.   Now for a prime, $\phi(p) = p-1$, so that means your equation has solutions when $p-1 \ge 4$, i. e. when $p \ge 5$.  We can check by brute force that $x_1^2 = 0 \mod 2$ and $x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 0 \mod 3$ have only the trivial solutions.  So the equation $x_1^2 + \cdots + x_{p-1}^2 = 0 \mod p$ has nontrivial solutions for all primes $p \ge 5$.

(Basically, this is a more explicit version of the second paragraph of Bjorn Poonen's answer.)

Comment: In fact, what I was trying to hint at by "small integers" was your solution with k=4 (for p at least 5); i.e., 2^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + ... + 1^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 = p.  (No need to count quadratic residues!)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is tangential in the sense that it is speaking of the *existence* of solutions rather than counting them all. But I rather suspect that you would find this interesting.

Suppose you have a quadratic form in at least thee variables over $\mathbb F_p$. Then the [Chevalley-Warning Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%2DWarning_theorem) would tell you that it has a nontrivial solution.

If you want to check out more, I refer you to the first chapter of J.-P. Serre's "A Course in Arithmetic", rather than the wikipedia page linked above.

Comment: Hi! I am reading the book "A course in arithmetic". I finished about 4 chapters by now. Thanks!